# STP packets dropped (1 packet every 2 seconds) when irrelevant multicast group joined on the interface

Tags: linux-networking, multicast, kernel-modules, stp, dropped

I'm trying to understand weird packet drop issue when joining particular multicast group.

I think this issue is related to patch introduced in kernel ver 2.6.37

```
Beginning with kernel 2.6.37, it has been changed the meaning of dropped
packet count. Before, dropped packets was most likely due to an error.
Now, the rx_dropped counter shows statistics for dropped frames because 
of:

Softnet backlog full -- (Measured from /proc/net/softnet_stat)
Bad / Unintended VLAN tags
Unknown / Unregistered protocols
IPv6 frames when the server is not configured for IPv6

If any frames meet those conditions, they are dropped before the 
protocol stack and the rx_dropped counter is incremented.
```

On a clean SLES11 SP3 I managed to reproduce this by joining STP multicast group (01:80:c2:00:00:00).

Without any changes, there's no packet drops in `/proc/net/dev` (RX) or `netstat -i` because my system has not joined STP multicast group (so ignoring packets).

When I join the STP multicast group I can see packet drops (1 packet every 2 secs) which I believe are dropped due to the patch introduced in kernel 2.6.37 (Unknown/Unregistered Protocols) and this is ok.

```
hostname:~ # ip maddr add 01:80:c2:00:00:00 dev eth1
```

My understanding is that When I modprobe llc/stp module into kernel it recognizes the protocol and therefore stops dropping the packets (tests prove that I am right).

Modprobing `llc` or `stp` module (depends on llc) "fixes" dropped packet issue.

Now, the question:

I have an application that joins multiple multicast groups when started. And for some reason **one** particular join triggers dropped packet issue (1 packet per 2 seconds).

The problem is, it is **not** stp multicast address `01:80:c2:00:00:00` but a totally different one (`01:00:5e:46:ac:04 aka 239.70.172.4`).
Inserting llc/stp module "fixes" dropped packet counter increment. All other multicast groups do not cause this problem e.g. (`01:00:5e:46:ac:02`) and also many others.

STP frames are the only one that appear on the interface every 2 seconds but their destination MAC address is 01:80:c2:00:00:00.

```
00:21:1b:4f:a3:bf > 01:80:c2:00:00:00, 802.3, length 119: LLC, dsap STP (0x42) Individual, ssap STP (0x42) Command, ctrl 0x03: STP 802.1s, Rapid STP, CIST Flags [Learn, Forward]
```

How is this possible? Why would 01:00:5e:46:ac:04 multicast group trigger this behaviour, like it would be somehow related to STP group and let frames/packets pass further through the stack?